# Hacer una cadena de if y recoger un valor para una variable cuando cumple con las condiciones

Tags: java, android

Lo que pasa es que hice una cadena de if() con hartas condiciones y espero recoger un valor distinto para "TipoAtencionX" dependiendo de cada una de las condiciones.

Ejemplo: Si cumple con la condicion 1, quiero que "TipoAtencionX" sea "atencion1". Si NO cumple con la condicion 1 y sí con la condicion 2, quiero que "TipoAtencionX" sea "atencion2". Si NO cumple con la condicion 1 y 2, pero sí con la condicion 3, quiero que "TipoAtencionX" sea "atencion3", etc.

Este es mi código, el problema es que siempre funciona sólo hasta el primer if y cuando no cumple con la condición 1 aún sigue trabajando con ese dato y la idea es que si no cumple lo evite o lo ignore y siga la cadena de if().

Este es mi código

```
if (TipoAtencion1.equals("no contiene")){
    TipoAtencionX  = "TipoAtencion1";
} else if (!TipoAtencion1.equals("no contiene") && TipoAtencion2.equals("no contiene")){
    TipoAtencionX = "TipoAtencion2";
} else if (!TipoAtencion1.equals("no contiene") && !TipoAtencion2.equals("no contiene") &&
    TipoAtencion3.equals("no contiene")){
    TipoAtencionX = "TipoAtencion3";
} else if (!TipoAtencion1.equals("no contiene") && !TipoAtencion2.equals("no contiene") &&
    !TipoAtencion3.equals("no contiene") && TipoAtencion4.equals("no contiene")){
     TipoAtencionX = "TipoAtencion4";
} else if (!TipoAtencion1.equals("no contiene") && !TipoAtencion2.equals("no contiene") &&
     !TipoAtencion3.equals("no contiene") && !TipoAtencion4.equals("no contiene")
     && TipoAtencion5.equals("no contiene")){
      TipoAtencionX = "TipoAtencion5";
} else if (!TipoAtencion1.equals("no contiene") && !TipoAtencion2.equals("no contiene") &&
      !TipoAtencion3.equals("no contiene") && !TipoAtencion4.equals("no contiene")
      && !TipoAtencion5.equals("no contiene")){
      etnuevotap.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ya tienes cinco tipos de atención registrados," +
      " no puedes tener más, elimina alguno.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracisa por su tiempo!

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con "cuando no cumple con la condición 1 aún sigue trabajando con ese dato"?

Comment: Me refiero a que aunque no cumpla con esa condición sigue ejecutando el código dentro del if... Al menos eso es lo que veía en el resultado de mi ejercicio, el valor se guardaba siempre aunque no cumpliera con la condición, no lo ignora y no sigue la cadena de if()...

Comment: Si no cumple la condicion es imposible que entre dentro del if.

Comment: No me refiero a que no cumpla, sino que sea distinto...

Comment: Si es distinto tampoco va a entrar nunca. Saltara al else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tus posibles ramas son

- A
- !A && B
- !A && !B && C
- !A && !B && !C && D

Pero, el `else` de `A` es precisamente `!A`

```
if (A) {
    ...  //A
} else {
  // Aquí se cumple !A
  if (B) {
     ...  // !A && B
  } else {
    // Aquí se cumple !A && !B
    if (C) {
      ... // !A && !B && C
    } else {
      // Aquí se cumple !A && !B && !C && D
    }
  }
```

Dicho lo cual, al llegar a este nivel empieza a ser complicado seguir los valores, y empieza a convenir replantearse si es posible obtener lo mismo de otra forma.

Por ejemplo, dado que está claro que buscas el primer elemento "no contiene", simplemente mete todos los elementos en una lista o array y recórrela hasta enconctrar el primer elemento válido.

Comment: Le agregué un poco más de código, pero con tu explicación y el ejemplo funciona super bien, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Si cumple siempre la primera condición no debes finalizarlo mientras no pases por las restantes condiciones, necesitas anidar los ifs:

```
if (TipoAtencion1.equals("no contiene")){
  TipoAtencionX  = "TipoAtencion1";

} else {
     if (TipoAtencion2.equals("no contiene")) {
       TipoAtencionX  = "TipoAtencion2";
     } else {
           ........
     }
}
```

O plantearlo desde la condición más restrictiva (en tu caso la última) a la menos restrictiva para que sólo entre en el primero si las cumple todas:

```
 if (!TipoAtencion1.equals("no contiene") && !TipoAtencion2.equals("no contiene") &&
    !TipoAtencion3.equals("no contiene") && !TipoAtencion4.equals("no contiene") &&
    !TipoAtencion5.equals("no contiene")) {
    etnuevotap.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ya tienes cinco tipos de atención registrados," +
        " no puedes tener más, elimina alguno.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (!TipoAtencion1.equals("no contiene") && !TipoAtencion2.equals("no contiene") &&
    !TipoAtencion3.equals("no contiene") && !TipoAtencion4.equals("no contiene") ) {
    TipoAtencionX = "TipoAtencion5";
} ....
```